# Why is there no extra channel for error or status?

Tags: database, tcp, client-server, stderr

I have a question on Client-Server-Computing.

**Why is there only one connection from the server back to the client?** In UNIX you normally have stdout and stderr.

Background:
Database-queries might take a much longer time than you expected.
Then you wonder if there is something wrong. Maybe the server is stuck in an endless loop. This can easily be the case because servers nowadays can be extended via procedures, triggers etc.

If there was an extra port for sending status messages from the server to the client the user could get the information "everything ok" e.g. via "executing node number 7 of the query execution plan".

These users who only would be puzzeld by such information could keep the message window closed.

**Is there a real technical problem or need those responsible for TCP standardisation just a hint?**

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a generic transport protocol and does not distinguish between different semantics, like status, error, data, ... Such semantics are added by the application protocol on top of TCP.

To provide different semantics it is not necessary to have different TCP connections. One could easily define an application protocol which allow messages with different semantics to be transferred over the same TCP connection. And such protocols exist, for example TLS (handshake messages, application data, alerts ...). But one could also do multiple TCP connections, like in FTP with different TCP connections for control and data.

So the question should be instead why a specific server application does not have the capability for status updates in parallel to queries. It is definitely not because of limitations from using TCP as transport layer, but because of limitations in the application itself.

Comment: Thank you for this sound answer. So it is definitly possible and as different RDBMS have different TCP-ports it is no general question (about SQL), but it is a decision of the programmers of every RDBMS on their own.